# Volume between a sphere and 4 planes

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, 3d, volume

Given the attached figure, we are interested in the volume between the sphere with radius R centered at $O$ given by the sphere equation $x^2 +y^2+z^2=R^2$ and the four planes as described:

Plane AOC with equation $a_{1}x+b_{1}y+c_{1}z = D_{1}$

Plane COB with equation $a_{2}x+b_{2}y+c_{2}z = D_{2}$

Plane AOB with equation $a_{3}x+b_{3}y+c_{3}z = D_{3}$

Plane ABC with equation $a_{4}x+b_{4}y+c_{4}z = D_{4}$

The resulting volume is the volume between the plane ABC and the spherical triangle. How can be extracted?

[Volume subtended by 3 points of sphere and the corresponding plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRlsz.png)

Comment: Cool question. If you're gonna ask about volume, why not ask about surface area bound by the Spherical Triangle too?

Comment: What have you tried? Were did you get stuck? The sphere is split into two halves, which one is of interest?

Comment: Random thoughts: Center of circle that touches the three vertices is the axis of the cap, the perpendicular to the plane is it's height. Then (re)define coordinates to make the mess simple.

Comment: @vonbrand       The problem is the methodology. Any height and coordinates are known.

Comment: Maybe you’ll find this useful: Call the variable perpendicular distance from the center to the centroid of the triangle $x$. On increasing $x$ the new triangle formed will be smaller than the original, but *similar*. Also, for any value of $x$ the distance of each vertex of the triangle from the centroid is $ \sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ by Pythagoras. So assuming you know the the vertex-centroid distance of the initial triangle you can use the similarity to relate the sides of any new triangle with $x$, use Heron’s formula for the area $A$ and integrate $ Adx$ from initial perp distance to R.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Once you have the tetrahedron $O,A,B,C$ then you can find the [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Tetrahedron)
 it subtends in $O$ by applying the formula given in the link.

From there you have the volume of the "spherical pyramid", and the rest follows easily.

Since you want an alternative approach as a check, the points $A,B,C$ lie on great circles, as they also lie on planes through the origin.
 They are therefore a [Spherical Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Area_and_spherical_excess), 
of which you know all the parameters once you have the vectors from the origin: vertices, sides, angles, etc.
 So you can use the formulas of spherical trigonometry to check.

Finally, if you want to go through integration, then use Cartesian coordinates.
Take , e.g., $OA$ as the $z$ axis. Take the longitudinal plane bisecting $OAB, OAC$ as the $xz$ plane, and get the relevant symmetric projections$B',C'$ of $B,C$ on the $xy$ plane.
Project the great circle on $OBC$ on the $xy$ plane: you get an ellipse with semi-axes $R \cos \theta, R$.
Integrate over $(x,y)$ laying inside the ellipse, and within the lines $OB', \,OC'$, and with $z$ ranging from the plane $OBC$ to the sphere.

Comment: Indeed but the problem is the volume of the spherical triangle given the solid angle . That's why i need an alternative approach to cross-check.

Comment: isn't V sph. triangle = V spher. Pyramid - V tetrah ?

Comment: Yes, but probably I am doing something wrong with the formula of volume of the spherical pyramid so I need an alternative approach to cross-check.

Comment: Maybe you need instead to fix first the equations of the planes: a) why 4 planes ?  b) The 3 planes through the origin shall have $D=0$, is it so ?

Comment: The wanted volume is limited by these 4 planes and the sphere.

Comment: aren't $A,B,C$ on the sphere ?

Comment: Yes A,B,C are on the sphere. I am interested in finding the volume through intersection of planes to cross - check the formula you referred above.

Comment: I've added some further lines.